# How to call context menu in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, contextmenu

Making this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html I have ListActivity-derived class and onCreateContextMenu, onContextItemSelected overrides. I think that it is like in Windows listbox: right-click listbox item, select popup menu item. However, I don't know how to execute this function in Android simulator: right-click on ListActivity item doesn't work, and I cannot see ContextMenu.

So, what should I do in Android emulator to see the context menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long click on list using mouse until options appears .

Answer (score 6):

Since the Android is designed for hand helds, there really is no idea of right clicking. On a hand held, the context menu is brought up with your finger by pressing a list item and holding until it comes up. In the simulator this becomes a click the mouse and hold.